# How can I get global pyramid request in socketio methods?

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid, python-socketio

I want to use python-socketio and I want to query my database from socketio methods. My db settings are saved in the pyramid request. But I don't understand how to get these settings without http-requests.

```
@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('connect ', sid)


@sio.event
def message(sid, data):
    # I want to query my database at this location
    sio.send(data)
    print('Server send', data)


@sio.event
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)
```

I was thinking of using ' pyramid.threadlocal.get_current_request ' but this method returns None.

I add database settings to the pyramid request by this code.

**__init__.py**

```
def db(request):
    session = session_maker(request)
    return session

...
config.add_request_method(db, reify=True)
```

**session_maker**

```
def session_returner(request, connect_line):
    engine = create_engine(connect_line, echo=debug)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    Session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    def cleanup(request):
        if request.exception is not None:
            session.rollback()
        session.close()

    request.add_finished_callback(cleanup)

    return session


def session_maker(request, settings=None):
    if settings is None:
        settings = get_settings(request)

    connect_line = 'postgresql://{user}:{password}@{postgre_server}:{bd_port}/{bd_name}'.format(user=settings['bd_user'], postgre_server=settings['postgre_server'], bd_port=settings['bd_port'],  password=settings['bd_password'],  bd_name=settings['bd_name'])
    return session_returner(request, connect_line)
```

Comment: Perhaps this [Pyramid Community Cookbook recipe page](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/deployment/gevent.html) has some guidance?

Comment: It appears that you're opening a new connection on every request. Apart from being a bit inefficient it also precludes from using the database connection with socket.io I think because there's no connection to the db in between requests.

Comment: @StevePiercy gevent-socketio was an old solution that does not work with the JavaScript Socket.io higher version than 9.6(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a request object, but obviously there isn't one by default when not serving a request. This can be done via:

```
request = pyramid.request.Request.blank('/')
request.registry = registry
pyramid.request.apply_request_extensions(request)

request.db.query(...)
```

This assumes you have access to the registry which was defined by the wsgi app. Something like `config.registry` or `app = config.make_wsgi_app(); registry = app.registry` or `request.registry` from another request.